# How to push existing RedHat BRMS project to remote git repository

Tags: git, drools, redhat-brms

I have an existing Redhat BRMS Project. I want to push all my Existing project assets present so far from local git to remote Git location( Github).

**Step 1** : I moved into the .git directory

`cd JBOSS_HOME/bin/.niogit/REPOSITORY_NAME.git`

**Step 2** : I have pointed my remote URL to github

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY_NAME.git`

**Step 3** : Create post-commit sh file inside hooks folder

```
git push origin master
chmod +x post-commit
```

**Step 4** : I added new data object and made a save. Nothing got reflected in my remote git .

Please let me know just in case if I missed something.

Comment: After step 4, you did a commit and push, right?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas do i have to manually do the git commit and push ? . I thought post-commit hook will take care of that

Comment: A post-commit hook only triggers after commit. So if you don't commit it doesn't trigger.

Comment: Also not only do you have to commit for the post-commit hook to trigger, the commit has to complete successfully. So any pre-commit hooks must be satisfied, etc..

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Agreed .  The commit is happening in workbench , whenever i added/modify a asset each save is getting commited. But the post commit hook is not getting triggered.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas One more thing what i observed was . If I manually do a "git push origin master" thorugh gitbash the changes are getting reflected in github

Answer (score 0):

Closing the issue. Points to be noted.

1. Make sure ssh keys which got created in your local machine gets added in remote github.
2. post-commit file should not have any extension (  like .sh )
3. This is optional, in mycase this worked after a long struggle. Restart the machine and try again.