# How can I `git push` from a script initiated by a cronjob?

Tags: bash, git, cron

I have the following script:

```bash
cd ~/path/to/repo ;
git pull ;
git add . ;
git commit -m "autocommit for repo" ;
git push ;
cd ~ ;
```

I have it run in a cronjob every minute. It works up until the `git push` command and then it does nothing. If I run the script manually it works fine. I updated the cronjob to write the output of running the script to a temp text file to see if `git push` was failing. It is not failing, it just isn't being ran at all it seems. The only output present is related to the `git commit` command. What might be going wrong?

I'm on a Mac running the latest macOS but I have tried it on my Linux machine as well with the same result.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: @Mureinik I have a folder of notes that I back up to GitHub. Preferably I wouldn't have to do this process manually every time I make changes.

Comment: No need for cron job: write a `post-commit` hook; push after every commit. Advantages: doesn't run where thre're no commits.

Comment: Checklist for cron jobs: Does it run under the same user? Does it run with the same shell environment? Does it properly authenticate (PAT for HTTPS, keypair for SSH)?

Comment: Thanks! And that makes sense, it probably is not properly authenticating.

Comment: @phd Looks like the issue was git-lfs (I have some media I store in this repo) not being found in the path of the user cron is operating under.

Comment: Note that Git, which attempts to be a good *version control* system (VCS), makes a *terrible* backup system to whatever extent it *is* a good VCS. macOS has Time Machine as a backup system, and Time Machine isn't bad as a backup system (and is therefore terrible as a VCS). VCS and backup are related but what makes something good at one of those jobs makes it bad at the other, and vice versa.

Comment: For an analogy (if that helps), think about these two sports: basketball and gymnastics. What makes someone a good basketball player? Well, in general, being *tall* helps enormously. What makes someone a good gymnast? Well, in general, being *short* helps enormously. So someone who's a great gymnast is probably not a good basketball player, and vice versa, however good shape they're in otherwise.

Comment: @torek Yeah I understand, I am just using `git` because I want to be able to keep track of the history of my edits. I also maintain a separate backup that doesn't keep track of edit history. I realize Time Machine can also keep track of edit history, but I switch back and forth between my Mac and a Linux machine and Time Machine doesn't work with Linux.

Comment: You might want to use ZFS on Linux here; ZFS has snapshots and you can stream a snapshot backup to, e.g., S3 (encrypted even!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I updated the cronjob to write the output of running the script to a temp text file to see if git push was failing

Make sure to [redirect both stdout and stderr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52332/7490), since most Git command produce outputs to stderr

```
*/1 * * * * /your/script.sh >> /your/script.log 2>&1
```

But a [post-commit client-side local hook is a good alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28042939/6309).

(As [noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67052697/6309), that means creating a push script named post-commit, without extension, as executable in your `.git/hooks` folder)